# How to add my Windows 8 partition into Ubuntu 12.04 partition

Tags: partitioning

I have installed a side by side Ubuntu 12.04 along with my Windows 8,

Now i want to delete Windows 8 completely and i want to add size to my Ubuntu partition fully.

What should i do now to increase my Ubuntu partition by adding Windows 8 drive space.
please help me...

I want the Ubuntu partition to be increased as i have given only 43 GB while installing .
i want to add windows 8 partition to my Ubuntu partition.
Thanking you.

Comment: I recommend that you install Gparted from the Ubuntu Software Center and make a screenshot of how your current partition setup looks when it is displayed in Gparted. Upload the screenshot to a photo sharing website and edit your question to include a link to the screenshot that you uploaded. This way the answer to your question will be able to tell you exactly what to do, including the new partition sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Simply delete Windows partition and then extend Ubuntu partition to free space using PartEd. Be sure to save important data before first operation.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at using gparted   http://gparted.sourceforge.net/ (graphical tool for editing partitions). It can do these things.  It might be simpler to format the windows partition (loosing all windows data) and use that partition to store media files or your home directory (you can use symlinks to let the operating system think files are somewhere when they are somewhere else) than to grow the partition which may mean lost data.  symlinks: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/creating-soft-link-or-symbolic-link/   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link